# Visual Studio Add-In automatically showing code file besides header file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, ide, visual-studio-addins

In Visual Studio 2010 C++ projects, I always have the header (.h) and the corresponding code file (.cpp) open at the same time.

I dock the code window of the header file to the left and the code file to the right.

Is there an add-in available for VS2010 which automatically does this for me?